# How to make async function to an ordinary synchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I would use an async function as normal synchronous function, I tried use await but it still doesn't work.

```
const getScript = (url) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const http = require('http'),
        https = require('https');

    let client = http;

    if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
        client = https;
    }

    client.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            resolve(data);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
});
};

async function getBody(url) {

(async (url) => {
    return ("qwe" + await getScript(url));
})(url);
}


console.log(getBody('http://myurl.com/myapi'));


console.log("end");
```

But it still doesn't load the data before the console.log "end". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous function cannot be converted to synchronous. *a* in *asynchronous* means that it's not synchronous. `async` can converted to regular function, but it will still be asynchronous.

Asynchronicity is contagious. Once it's `async` (promise-based), it's preferable to stick to promise control flow.

There should be top-level `async` function at some point, and `async` IIFE inside `getBody` is redundant. It should be:

```
async function getBody(url) {
    return ("qwe" + await getScript(url));
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await getBody('http://myurl.com/myapi'));
    console.log("end");
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be await not async

```
async function getBody(url) {

(await (url) => {
    return ("qwe" + await getScript(url));
})(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are not awaiting for the result.Here when the IIFE is been executed (which is async) it returned a promise. You are not awaiting for the IIFE to be resolved.
Thus you should simply add await in front of IIFE like -

```
async function getBody(url) {
    await (async (url) => { // add await before executing this function right away
        return ("qwe" + await getScript(url));
    })(url);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
async function getBody(url) {
    let r = await getScript(url));
    return ("qwe" + r);
}

(async () => {
    let b = await getBody('http://myurl.com/myapi')
    console.log(b);
    console.log("end");
}) ();
```